# __autoreleasing for return value in ARC Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

According to Cocoa's "Create Rule" a method that returns a newly instantiated object must begin with either `new`, `create`, or `copy` if ownership is transferred to the caller.

Let's say I have a class that implements a factory method called `(NSObject *)getCorrectObject`.

This method will return a **new instance** of the correct subclass of the callee (determined by some internal state of the callee). Technically this method does not follow the "Create Rule" and could lead to memory leaks in non-ARC environments.

Would it be possible to instead use `(NSObject *__autoreleasing)getCorrectObject` to avoid using `new` or `create` in this case?

In non-ARC I would return an autoreleased object, but I'm not entirely sure if `__autoreleasing` works for anything other than In/Out parameters.

Comment: What you really ought to do is to either change the name of your API, or what it does instead of fighting the naming convention.

Comment: "Technically this method does not follow the "Create Rule" and could lead to memory leaks in non-ARC environments." Whether there is a leak depends on whether the method does an unbalanced retain. Whether it returns a new instance or existing instance is irrelevant.

Comment: Ya, I worded this question poorly. It's non-obvious in ARC whether a new instance has an unbalanced retain or not (unless using alloc, copy, mutableCopy, new). What I had meant was could you use `__autoreleasing` in the return type to make it explicit that this is an autoreleased value being returned to the caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to Cocoa's "Create Rule" a method that returns a newly instantiated object must begin with either new, create, or copy if ownership is transferred to the caller.

This isn't called the Create Rule (and isn't correct). The Create Rule is a [Core Foundation rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html) related to the words Create and Copy. Cocoa has [a different rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) related to “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”.

> Let's say I have a class that implements a factory method called (NSObject *)getCorrectObject.

Then it would be incorrectly named. Starting a method with `get` indicates that it returns a value by reference. The correct signature would be:

```
+ (BOOL)getCorrectObject(NSObject**)result;
```

> This method will return a new instance of the correct subclass of the callee (determined by some internal state of the callee). Technically this method does not follow the "Create Rule" and could lead to memory leaks in non-ARC environments.

That is not based on whether it is a new instance. It's based on whether it includes an unbalanced `retain`.

Methods that begin with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” should return an object with one unbalanced `retain`. Other methods should return an object that has an equal number of `retain` and `autorelease` attached to it.

If for some reason you have to violate these naming rules (and you *really* don't want to violate these rules), the correct way to indicate it to ARC is by using `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` (see `Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h` for all the macros). This only assists ARC in correctly fixing your memory management when dealing with mixed ARC/Retain code in cases where it is impossible to fix your incorrect naming. Pure ARC code doesn't need this; it'll balance out either way. Pure Retain code won't be helped by this. The caller has to do the right thing (and so has to just know that you did it wrong and compensate).

Note that as long as you're using ARC throughout the project (and you really, really should be), most of this won't matter a lot in practice. ARC will balance everything out for you pretty much no matter what you name things, since you're not in charge of adding the retains, releases, and autoreleases anyway.

Comment: So at the end of the day this method signature really makes no sense semantically, and if I want to really confuse people more then I use `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED`. Gotchya.

Comment: @Awesome-o: No, just `(NSObject *)getCorrectObject` is fine.